# Is there any way to retroactively store model output in a variable?

Tags: r

Let's say I have just run a large linear regression that has taken a considerable amount of time to run. However, I forgot to assign the model to a variable prior to running it, i.e. 
    lm(outcome ~ iv1 + iv2)

Instead of

```
fit <- lm(outcome ~ iv1 + iv2)
```

Is there a way to retroactively assign the final output to a variable after its been run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have not run anything else in the interim, the last object created is stored in `.Last.value`.

```
fit <- .Last.value
```